# Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets. Then, prove that $A - B = A$ iff $B - A = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Can someone help me with this question?

Question: Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets. Then, prove that

$$A - B = A \Longleftrightarrow B - A = B$$

Comment: That symbol font is illegible on my phone.

Comment: *Hint:*  It may be easier to show that $A\setminus B=A\iff A\cap B=\emptyset$.  Then, as $A\cap B=B\cap A$ the desired original statement follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Math SE!

**Motivation**

Given two sets, $A$ and $B$, if no part of $B$ is in $A$, then the two sets must be disjoint. The converse is also true i.e. if the two sets are disjoint, then no part of $B$ can be in $A$. If you have trouble seeing this, draw a simple Venn diagram.

**Idea**

Here, I will only prove the $\implies$ direction as the same argument can be used to prove the $\impliedby$ direction.

The proof is very short and sweet.

If $A - B = A$,

then $A \cap B = \emptyset = B \cap A$.

$\because B \cap A = \emptyset$

$\therefore B - A = B$